# How can you sync an SVN repository thats been exported?

Tags: svn, export, updates

I wanted to grab the latest changes to SVN without overwriting local changes... but I dont have the full fileset for the files that have changed in svn. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with svn update? It won't overwrite your local changes. Exported svn repositories are not meant to be synchronized, as there subversion 'information' has been stripped on purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a svn update your local changes will not be lost...they will be merged together...What i don't understand is how you have changed files but not all in SVN ?...